# Balancing out in an orthogonal design

Tags: experiment-design, descriptive-statistics, combinatorics, orthogonal, latin-square

A definition of orthogonality in the context of statistics is

> An experimental design is orthogonal if the effects of any factor
>   balance out (sum to zero) across the effects of the other factors.

Being a non-native speaker, I am not sure I understand that. With my favourite example of a latin square, how can I see this condition is satisfied?

```
  123
1 ABC
2 BCA
3 CAB
```

How does this show the variables are orthogonal?

Answer (score 1):

Well, treatments A,B and C are orthogonal to rows and columns. Lets say there is an linear effect on yield $Y$ by rows (columns treated equally).  Code that linear effect of row by $-r,0,r$ (we can center it since the mean effect is modelled by the intercept in a linear model). Write a linear model (without interactions) as
$$
   Y_{ij}=\mu + r i + c j + \beta_t + \text{error}
$$
where rows $i$ and columns $j$ are coded as $-1,0,1$. Then the mean observation of the three plots with treatment A (others are equal) is given by
$$
   \mu +\frac13 (-r +0 + r) + \frac13 (-c+0+c)+\beta_A = \mu + \beta_A
$$
which is just the definition of orthogonality that you gave.  We only used that the plots are organized in a latin square, whatever latin square will do.